How to combine lists on the command line (jq)?
I have two files with JSON lists:
File 1
[0,1,2]
["a", "b", "c"]

File 2
[3,4,5]
["d", "e", "f"]

How can I use jq or a similar command line tool to combine the lists in each line? The result from combining the two files above should be :
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]


What have you tried already?

Read both files into an array, use transpose to combine by their index, and perform the operation on the resulting array, i.e. add the subarrays.
jq -nc --slurpfile f1 file1.json --slurpfile f2 file2.json \
  '[$f1, $f2] | transpose[] | add'

Alternatively, read them into one array, and split that single array in half to produce the two subarrays:
jq -sc '[.[:length/2], .[length/2:]] | transpose[] | add' file1.json file2.json

Output:
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
["a","b","c","d","e","f"]

